# HTTP 403 (error 13) with Zend CE on OS X

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, permissions, zend-server-ce

I'm getting a HTTP 403, with permission error 13 (file system?) using Apache (bundled with Zend Server) on OS X 10.7.4.

```
[Thu May 17 16:40:58 2012] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Here's my config in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/shamil/Documents/Sites/shamil_blog"

  ServerName blog.shamil.local
  ServerAlias blog.shamil.local
  ErrorLog "logs/shamil_blog-error_log"
  CustomLog "logs/shamil_blog-access_log" common

  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory /Users/shamil/Documents/Sites/shamil_blog>
      Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have set the appropriate permissions on the shamil_blog folder:

```
 drwxrwxrwx  25 shamil  staff   850 May 17 16:01 shamil_blog
```

and on the Sites folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx   4 shamil  staff    136 May 17 15:59 Sites
```

So, why am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the permissions on /Users, /Users/shamil, /Users/shamil/Documents, /Users/shamil/Documents/Sites.  Also, I don't know OS X well enough, what user does the web server run under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage, I assume the permissions on /User are too restrictive, and Apache can't even get to the Document Root.  Remember, the Apache user ID will need execute rights to any directory it needs to traverse to get to the Document Root.